# several import errors in android studio + unable to compile

Tags: android, compiler-errors

Today I wanted to start working on my app after some time. I have tried to compile the old project but now I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: Asset package include '/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar' not found.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Additionally, most of the import fail. For example, all the following give me the red error message "cannot import name ..."

```
 import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
```

In order to solve the issue, I have tried to do "Invalidate Cache", but it doesn't work. I have no idea where this error comes from.
I have the impression that I have touched something which changed the configuration of my Android Studio.
Help please!

Answer (score 1):

As this is your first time opening the app in a while, I would recommend using SDK manager to get the latest SDKs that you use.

Secondly I would check your build.gradle file to see if any of the dependencies used are still correct (they may have newer versions available).

Comment: in fact, if I open the build.gradle, I have some problems: it is possible to read that "dependencies cannot be applied to 'groovy.lang.Closure' this inspection reports assignments with incompatible types' ".maybe is this the origin of my problems?